# Is there a way to "mirror" a website that is a Tor site?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, torsocks

I have used HTTrack for regular websites but I want to be able to create a local mirror of a site I can get to via the Tor Browser.  Is there such an application out there?  I run Windows 10 but can setup a Linux VM if that is what I need to be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Choose one:

- Use mirror software that natively supports proxying over socks5 and configure it to proxy over Tor/Tor Browser's socks port
- Use `torsocks` or similar
- Run the mirror software on a computer/VM that transparently does everything over Tor